# What is the correct way to configure App.Config files when using wcf services

Tags: wpf, vb.net, wcf, visual-studio-2015, wcf-binding

Let's say that I have a simple WPF or Winforms solution.  To that solution I add a new project (based on a class library template , which I then reference in the main project) which is intended to be a data layer containing an entity framework data model.  When I create the data model in the new project the connection string that it uses gets added to the app.config file of the main project in the solution.

Now let us say that I want to add two more projects to the solution (both of which will again be based on class libraries) to contain details of WCF services that I wish to use.  In each case I add the WCF service by using the ADD Service Reference option from the right click context menu of the projects.

Unlike the data model project though the bindings for the service model get added to the local projects app.config file ass opposed to the app.config file of the main start-up project.

Should I simply copy those bindings to the start-up project's app.config file, or should I copy and then delete, or in fact should I be doing something completely different.  Thus far trying combination of the first two suggestions I get error messages connected with endpoint configuration, however my knowledge of WCF is not really sufficiently good to fully understand the MSDN articles that the error list points me to.

Note that if the service references are added to the main project I get no errors whatsoever, so I figure this must be a configuration problem of some description.

Would anyone be able to provide the correct procedure for adding projects that essentially contain no more than a WCF service reference to an existing visual studio solution.

Edit

The screenshot below shows my main app.cofig file after having copied over the bindings configurations from the two service contracts. I'm not sure whether I should have commented out the bit that I did or not, I had thought that by doing so I might get rid of the blue squiggly underlines telling me the following (which I must admit to not understanding):

```
Warning     The 'contract' attribute is invalid - The value 'ErsLiveService.IERSAPIService' is invalid according to its datatype 'clientContractType' - The Enumeration constraint failed.
```

[image]

Comment: _"Should I simply copy those bindings to the start-up project's app.config file"_ - yes.

Comment: @CodeCaster Thank you for your comment.  I followed your suggestion, but I suspect I missed something in the process.  I have amended the question accordingly and would be interested in your comments.  I guess I've missed something simple but quite what I have no idea.

Comment: You need a reference from the startup application to the library containing the service reference. If that reference is there, you can safely ignore this warning.

Comment: But that would create a circular dependency, given that the two service projects are already referenced in the main project from where I intend to use them.

Comment: Then you need to split up your projects. The startup application needs a reference to the assemblies containing the service references, period.

Comment: Aha, so no need to copy the service bindings from those separate projects' app.config files over to the main app.config of the primary project.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your patience and help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You're likely getting the blue squigglies because the namespace `ErsTestService` is defined within the project in which you created the service reference. If the root namespace of that project is `MyServiceReferenceProject` then try changing the namespace to `MyServiceReferenceProject.ErsTestService.IERSAPIService`.